# CLLocationManager geofencing not working

Tags: cllocationmanager

I am trying to get geofencing working in CoreLocation but even though I am standing right on top of the lat/long point, didEnterRegion never gets called.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    myLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    myLocationManager.delegate = self
    myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
        myLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {

        let geoSet = arrLocSets[2]
        let regionLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: geoSet[0], longitude: geoSet[1])
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: regionLocation.coordinate, radius: 30, identifier: "region1")
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = false

        myLocationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)

        print(myLocationManager.monitoredRegions)
    }

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        myLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

the print call logs this:

```
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'region1', center:<+40.20675900,-75.48613300>, radius:30.00m)]
```

which is correct.

the print call in

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        print("started monitoring!")
    }
```

prints to the log so I know at least the monitoring started.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

    print(region)
    /*
    if let region = region as? CLCircularRegion {

        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Entered Region", message: "You found the region \(region.identifier)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
     */
}
```

and here's a screen capture from my phone, where I was tracking lat/long. (Ignore the bottom labels, those are previous hard coded coordinates).

I put a break point in didEnterRegion and it never get triggered. 206851 and 206759 should be within a 30M diameter of each other? No? Did I miss a set up step?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

didEnterRegion/didExitRegion happens on status change only. When starting to monitor for a region while being inside of the region you will not receive didEnterRegion.

Start walking out until didExitRegion happens, and this will "rearm" the region for didEnterRegion events, now you can walk back in.

Just do not be surprised that you will have to walk much more than 30m in each direction to trigger the events. Be prepared for up to 300 meters journey - really depends on your speed and (wireless) environment. Region monitoring does not involve GPS at all, it is all about wifi/cell tower triangulation - depends on coverage, quality of prior measurements and it is not "real time", as it is driven by wifi/cell scans.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did see that Apple recommends a minimum of 200 meters for the didEnterRegion to work. But even then I wasn't getting results. This code does exactly what I need it to do:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978966/cllocation-distancefromlocation-works-better-than-checking-a-region

Just have to make sure it can scale. The app won't be checking location constantly, the user can activate it when they are close to the point, then when the point is reached, they can turn it off.